# jQuery Internationalization: Getting properties string outside the callback function

Tags: jquery, internationalization

I'm loading locale bundles when page language is changed.

```
$("#langSelector").change(function() {
    document.location = this.value;     // eg. ?lang=en
    loadBundles(this.value.substring(6));
});

function loadBundles(lang) {
    jQuery.i18n.properties({
        name:'Messages',
        path:'i18n/',   // Location path
        mode:'both',
        language: lang,
        callback: function() {
            // both works fine.
            // alert(confirm_cancel);
            alert(jQuery.i18n.prop('confirm_cancel'));
        }
    });
}
```

Means locale specific message is properly popped up inside the `callback`.
I want this (locale) message to get displayed on cancel button click event, like this

```
$("#cancelButton").click(function() {
    alert(jQuery.i18n.prop('confirm_cancel'));
});
```

Please help how can I get locale string value outside the callback function. Thanks!

Comment: You could put the click assignment inside the callback, but make sure to unbind the click first

Comment: @mplungjan, I've tried putting the cancel click function inside callback, but that doesn't work. Can you please provide some code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was calling the `loadBundle(lang)` at wrong event. Since page reloads after changing locale, all i18n properties get vanished. Solution is to loadBundle when page becomes ready.
Here is my jQuery for that:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var lang = getURLParameter("lang");
    loadBundles(lang);
});

function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null;
}

function loadBundles(lang) {
    jQuery.i18n.properties({
        name:'Messages',
        path:'i18n/',
        mode:'both',
        language: lang,
        callback: function() {}
    });
}

$("#langSelector").change(function() {
    document.location = this.value;
});

$("#cancelButton").click(function() {
    confirm(confirm_cancel);
});
```

Now its' loading locale specific properties for js messages.

Answer (score 0):

Does this not work?

```
callback: function() {
    $("#cancelButton").off("click").on("click",function() {
      alert(jQuery.i18n.prop('confirm_cancel'));
    });
}
```

Comment: its' not working sir. It pops 'confirm_cancel' instead of confirm_cancel string value from properties file.
Same is the result when I handle cancel button click outside the callback.

Comment: can you put a test page on the net for me to debug?